# Быстрый поиск файла на сервере по его названию

Tags: php

Приветствую.

Имеется такая вот функция

```
function search_file($dir, $tosearch)
{
    $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), Array(
        ".",
        ".."
    ));
    foreach ($files as $d) {
        if (!is_dir($dir . "/" . $d)) {
            if ($d == $tosearch)
                return $dir . "/" . $d;
        } else {
            $res = search_file($dir . "/" . $d, $tosearch);
            if ($res)
                return $res;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Собственно она работает, но работает довольно медленно. Что нужно заменить (или вообще переписать), чтобы поиск осуществлялся более быстро? Вложенность папок может быть любой.

P.S. на сервере с SSD диском поиск бы явно осуществлялся быстрее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как один из возможных вариантов

```
<?php
function search_file($dir, $tosearch) {
  return `find $dir -name $tosearch`;
}
```

Comment: А если у нас несколько одинаковых файлов?

Comment: @vitagame Вам вернется несколько строк, при желании ее можно разбить функцией explode() по символу PHP_EOL и вы получите массив, каждый элемент которого соответствует одному файлу.

Comment: Ясно. Но вариант что-то не особо скоростной.

Comment: @vitagame, если хотите быстрее - придется строить индекс по файловой системе и регулярно его обновлять. Вообще это делает и операционная система и если у вас достаточно свободной оперативной памяти, повторные запросы будут выполняться быстрее. Однако, как вариант вы можете просто прочитать дерево нужных вам файлов в memcached, хранить там и время от времени обновлять.

Comment: а можете подробней обо всём этом написать? Мемкешедом вообще не пользовался.